# code folding in Visual Studio for F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I find that I tend to write long source files in F#. Some open source projects in F# also have long source files, e.g. FPersec and F# for excel.

So it would be very helpful if code folding (even very limited support) is available in VS for F#. E.g. in a module, we can fold out functions that are stable, only leave functions that are subject to change unfold.

Is this feature easy to be supported, e.g. by a third party vendor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not available in F# (neither `#region`, nor folding of, for example, `let` bindings or `type` declarations as in C#).

I would also love to see this in future versions of F# - in fact, I tried writing a prototype of this feature during my internship at MSR, but it was (sadly) more difficult than it looked at first, so the code never reached the production quality and there were many far more important things that the F# team needed to focus on before the VS 2010 release...

Regarding third party support - If it is possible to implement code folding as an addition to the existing F# language service, then it should be possible (simply by looking for some special comments such as `(* #region Some name*)`), but I'm not 100% sure if that can be added by some plugin or macro.

Comment: As cool as it would be to have code folding I wish the team work on debugger support for the pipe operator.  Being able to break on lines that start with `|>` would be awesome.

Answer (score 13):

Folding of F# code is possible with [F# Outlinig](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bec977b8-c9d9-4926-999e-e50c4498df8a) Visual Studo extension. I can also recommend to look at [F# Depth Colorizer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0713522e-27e6-463f-830a-cb8f08e467c4/).

Comment: F# Outlining does not currently work with keyboard shortcuts, e.g. Ctrl+m, Ctrl+m normally toggles outlining, but not with F# Outlining :(

Comment: It seems F# Depth Colorizer is not available for 2015 studio. Power Pack declares that it has the feature but in fact there are only indentation guides which in turn are so bleak that I needed to install separate extension to start in fact using them. Though the guides are good I would still try the colorizer - the idea is appealing.