# How can you organise F# code in a similar way to C# regions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#

Is there a feature equivalent to C#'s regions for being able to group code into named blocks and collapse and expand them?

Alternatively, are there any workarounds or third party tools available to achieve the same result?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad thing that F# does not utilize regions. I wish C# didn't either.

Comment: There is no answer to this question other than the designers of the language chose not to include it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843785/1181338

Comment: @Bernard - how can you wish it didn't? Just don't use them?

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrates to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @SkonJeet, that's very easy to say until you have to work on someone else's code.

Comment: @SkonJeet: I find that regions are abused (e.g. nested regions). Also, I don't like "hiding" code like this. I'd rather see everything all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843401/code-folding-in-visual-studio-for-f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possible workaround might be using [F# Outlining](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bec977b8-c9d9-4926-999e-e50c4498df8a) VS Extension that provides `//#region` outlining functionality. I use it with VS2010 for couple of months without any problems and find it very convenient:

```
[-]//#region Region Name
   --lines of F# code--
   --lines of F# code--
   --lines of F# code--
   //#endregion
```

with one click collapses to

```
[+]Region Name
```

and back.

Answer (score 1):

I found times ago (out of mine curiosity) the link the was searching on for asking this question.

If you look at [Regions and navigation bar for F# in Visual Studio](http://tomasp.net/blog/regions-navigation.aspx) the guy seems implemented an experimental feature. Post of firsts of 2012, so it's pretty fresh stuff.

Should say that I didn't try it till now.

Good luck.